# "service restart" working although init.d script doesn't support "restart"

Tags: raspbian-stretch, services, init.d

I wrote the following script `/etc/init.d/tomcat` in order to manage my manually-installed Apache Tomcat server as a service:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/tomcat -- startup script for the Tomcat servlet engine
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tomcat
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Tomcat.
# Description:       Start the Tomcat servlet engine.
### END INIT INFO

export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat"
case "$1" in
start)
  if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh ];
  then
    $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
  fi
  ;;
stop)
  if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh ];
  then
    $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
  fi
  ;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Then, I executed the following commands and now the service is working fine:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/tomcat
sudo update-rc.d tomcat defaults
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

As you can see, **the `tomcat` script supports only `start` and `stop`**, no `restart` case is present, but I noticed that **if I launch `sudo service tomcat restart`, the service is effectively restarted**. How is it possible? I find no way to see which commands are issued behind the scenes.

As a counterproof, if I issue `sudo service tomcat qwerty` I get `Usage: /etc/init.d/tomcat {start|stop}` Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using old style **SysV** init scripts but since *Raspbian Jessie* SysV init isn't used anymore. It is replaced by **systemd**. Only for compatibility *systemd* emulates *SysV* so your init.d/script in practice is a *systemd unit* and any *systemd unit* can be restarted by default. You can verify it with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status tomcat.service
```

This should give you in the second line:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat; generated)
```

The important word is "*generated*". You can look what *systemd* has done with your old service to get a unit with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl cat tomcat.service
```

This is done by *systemd-sysv-generator*. Look at `man systemd-sysv-generator` and more general at `man systemd.generator`. Just for new services it is really time to switch over direct to *systemd*. Your init.d/service as systemd unit should look similar to this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat servlet engine
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Probably this has to be tuned to your needs. I don't know what the scripts do. Maybe you have to use `Type=forking` and select other dependencies. Look at `man systemd.unit` and `man systemd.service`.